# How can I change the target server type for a trace template?

Tags: sql-server, profiler

I've got a .tdf SQL Server Profiler trace template someone wants me to run but the template is targeting SS 2008 R2. While my SSMS is 2008 R2 the server I need to trace is SS 2005. When attempting to trace the server the server type is locked (generated from the actual server) so I can't just select the template I need while it's marked as a different SS version..

[image: Trace Template Properties window]

How can I change which server type the trade template is targeting? I've tried `File > Templates > Edit Templates...` but there doesn't seem to be an option to change this. Is it possible to change the target server version or does the whole trace have to be made again from scratch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you open Profiler, go to File > Templates > Import and choose your .tdf file.

You will have a new user trace template with the name [filename] (without the .tdf). Go to File > Templates > Edit and pick the trace template you imported. You should then be able to edit the server type by pulling the dropdown:

[image]

Then you can save the template and that should be the server type when you start a new trace using that template.

Comment: Okay, that does work. Important to note that when you pick the different server type, the template name disappears (it re-filters the templates to show you the selected server type's templates), but if you save it *does* edit the selected template. Disorienting, but now I know.

Comment: @Ben Yeah it is weird. Profiler's on the chopping block - embrace Extended Events now.

Comment: I had to use the technique recommended by @mcw0933 below.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore; when I switch between server types it automatically selects the "default" template for that type.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using Profiler 2012, talking to 2008, 2008 R2, and 2012 databases.  I had to use a slightly different workflow than in the [accepted answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/23421).

When I try to follow that workflow, to migrate a template from 2008 to 2012, the Select template name dropdown depopulates, and clicking Save or Save As prompts me to choose a template to save.

[image]

Instead, copy your template from the 2012 profiler, 2008 templates folder (should be `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\SQL Profiler\11.0\Templates\Microsoft SQL Server\100`) to the 2012 profiler, 2012 templates folder (should be `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\SQL Profiler\11.0\Templates\Microsoft SQL Server\110`)

Now, go to `File > New Trace...` and choose the copied template to perform a trace on a 2012 server.  Verify the trace is running and capturing what you want.

At this point, you're pretty good - you can use the copied template to start traces.  But if you want to make modifications on it, when you go to `File > Templates > Edit Template...` and choose Events Selection you get a prompt indicating the trace is in the wrong format:

[image]

To save it in the new format: start the trace running using `File > New Trace...` as mentioned above, then *with the trace running* do `File > Save As > Trace Template...` and choose a new name.  You can now delete the originally copied template, and use the newly saved template in its place.

Comment: This technique worked for me, while the accepted answer did not.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is only need change two bytes in tdf file.  I created a tiny PowerShell script to do that. [mssql.profiler.template.sql_ver.chg.ps1](https://github.com/TEH30P/MSSQL.Profiler) (GitHub)

```
<# 
.SYNOPSIS
    Changing sql server target version in *.tdf (profiler trace template) file.
.DESCRIPTION
    Changing sql server target version in *.tdf (trace template) file.
    To create *.tdf go to <SQL Server Profiler>\"File"\"Templates"\"Export Template...". To load *.tdf into templates list go to <SQL Server Profiler>\"File"\"Templates"\"Import Template..."
.PARAMETER iPath
    Source *.tdf file.
.PARAMETER iPathNew
    Destination *.tdf file. If ommitted then file $iPath will be rewrited. If file $iPathNew exists it will be overwrited.
.PARAMETER iVerNew
    Required target MS SQL Version for trace template in format 'X.X' or 'X'.
    Eg: 10.5 for MS SQL Server 2008 R2, 11 for MS SQL Server 2012. You can google it with query "ms sql versions".
.INPUTS
    <none>
.OUTPUTS
    <none>
.EXAMPLE
    mssql.profiler.template.sql_ver.chg.ps1 try_105.tdf try_13.tdf 13
    Will create file try_13.tdf with target sql server 2016 (version 13.0).
.LINK
    https://github.com/TEH30P/MSSQL.Profiler
#>

param
(   [parameter(Mandatory=1, position=0)][String]$iPath
,   [parameter(Mandatory=0, position=1)][String]$iPathNew
,   [parameter(Mandatory=0, position=2)][String]$iVerNew
)

try {

if ([IO.Path]::GetExtension($iPath) -ne '.tdf')
{   [String]$Answ = Read-Host -Prompt 'It is not a *.tdf file. Are you sure? {Y|[N]}';

    if (!$Answ.Length -or $Answ -eq 'N')
    {   throw 'Canceled'}
}

[String]$PathAbs = (Convert-Path $iPath);
[Byte[]]$aBuff = [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($PathAbs);

if ($aBuff.Count -le 391)
{   throw 'File is to small. Possible corrupted.'}

if ([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($iVerNew))
{   $iVerNew = Read-Host -Prompt "Current version is $($aBuff[390]).$($aBuff[391]). Enter new version:";

    if (!$iVerNew.Length)
    {   throw 'Canceled'}
}

[Version]$Ver = New-Object Version;
[UInt32]$VerMajor = 0;
[UInt32]$VerMinor = 0;

if (![UInt32]::TryParse($iVerNew, [ref]$VerMajor))
{   [Version]$iVerNew | % {$VerMajor = $_.Major; $VerMinor = "$($_.Minor)0".Substring(0,2)}}

$aBuff[390] = $VerMajor;
$aBuff[391] = $VerMinor;

if (![String]::IsNullOrEmpty($iPathNew))
{   [String]$PathAbs = (Convert-Path $iPathNew)}

[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($PathAbs, $aBuff);

} catch 
{   throw}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful since newer versions of Profiler seem less tolerant to mismatched template versions.  Instead of using your script, I copied a 2016 template from the `130` folder into the `140` folder and then opened it in a hex editor and changed the byte at offset **390** from `0x0D` (13 - v2016) to `0x0E` (14 - v2017).  Pretty easy.

Comment: Hex editing worked for me too, changing byte offset 390 (0x186) from 0x0B to 0x0E. Having to do this is so stupid, but thanks for the shortcut.